# v1 function for uuid not working for react native expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have the following code:

```
const handlefb = async () => {
    const fb = sRef(storage, `paramKey/${feedback + v1()}`);
    uploadString(fb, todoDatafb).then((snapshot) => {
      console.log('Uploaded new feedback')
    })
```

According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid, v1 is for `Create a version 1 (timestamp) UUID`. But it does not generate a timestamp for me.

Refer to screenshot of the file:

[image]

How come? Am I using the function wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is working as expected. It's generating a uuid. v1 does not generate a timestamp, it generates a time-based uuid. If you want a timestamp, just use the JavaScript `Date` object.

Comment: Oh. Looks like I misunderstand ```Create a version 1 (timestamp) UUID```. Thanks for the explanation and suggestion !